# Predicates and OrderBy , Func

Tags: c#, lambda, predicate, func

I understand that predicates are delegate to function which return bool and take generic parameter, I understand that when I say:

```
mycustomer => mycustomer.fullname == 1
```

It actually means:

```
delegate (Customer mycustomer)
{
  return mycustomer.fullName == "John";
}
```

The paramter I'm passing in when I pass this lambda expression is:

`public delegate bool Criteria<T>(T value)` which is natively called Predicate

But what I don't understand is what it means when I say `mycustomer=>mycustomer.fullname`

In `customers.OrderBy(mycustomer=>mycustomer.fullname);`

How do I implement something like `OrderBy`? How do I tell a method which property to do action on ! like the previous example?

By example here is a case I want to make a method which get all values of a collection for a specific property :

```
list<string> mylist = customers.GetPropertyValues(cus=>cus.Fullname);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Predicate` is a function returning a `bool`. `mycustomer=>mycustomer.fullname` is a `Func<Cutomer, string>` (I guess `fullname` is of type `string`). You should read about iterators (IEnumerable, yield, ...). If you are working with databases and such - it's all about expression trees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Func<TElement,TKey>` is used to create an `IComparer<TKey>` which is used internally in an `OrderedEnumerable` to sort the items.  When you do:

```
var items = myList.OrderBy(i => i.SomeProperty);
```

The `OrderedEnumerable` type is creating an `IComparer<TKey>` internally.  In the above example, if `i.SomeProperty` were a `String` it would create an instance of `IComparer<String>` and then sort the items in the source enumerable using that comprarer on the `SomeProperty` member.

In your last case:

```
list<string> mylist = customers.GetPropertyValues(cus=>cus.Fullname);
```

You do this using `Select`:

```
var names = customers.Select(c => c.Fullname);
```

Which will return an enumerable of `String` names.  In the `Select` method, the `Func<TSource, TResult>` is used to select the target element to be added to the result.

To replicate this yourself, you could do:

```
public static IEnumerable<TMember> GetPropertyValues<TSource, TMember>
  (this IEnumerable<TSource> enumerable, Func<TSource, TMember> selector)
{
  if (enumerable == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("enumerable");

  foreach (TSource item in enumerable)
  {
    yield return selector(item);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your respond but i know i can use customers.select(c=>c.fullname) i just want to know how to implement something like that im not actually looking for getting values of a property i was just giving an example , the question is how to Implement a method like customers.GetPropertyValues(cus=>cus.Fullname); or customers.Select(c => c.Fullname); any method that you can specify a property name by using lambda expression.

Answer (score 2):

You can create something like this:

```
static class ExtensionClass
{
    static IEnumerable<V> GetPropertyValues<T, V>(this IList<T> collection, Func<T, V> func)
    {
        foreach(var item in collection)
        {
            yield retun func(item);
        }
    }
}
```

But I really don't understand why Select method doesn't suite you.

Comment: im not against the select method , the thing is it doesnt answer the question , but your answer does ! i accepted your answer thank you so much , very nice

Answer (score 2):

> but what i dont understand is what it means when i say mycustomer=>mycustomer.fullname

It's the same thing as your delegate example except it only returns the fullName. Passed as a lambda so that it can be lazy evaluated.

If you want to create a method that works like `OrderBy`, besides that your GetPropertyValues seems to be the same as `customers.Select(c => c.Fullname)`, then you'll have to dive into the sea of generics and extension methods. `OrderBy` is actually just an extension method on `IEnumerable` defined as

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector
)
```

It looks like the answer from @Mike is an example of that and also a reimplementation of LINQ `Select`.

Answer (score 1):

The `OrderBy Extension Method` on class `Enumerable` takes a method of type `Func` as argument. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-5.0) is the documentation.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/csharpfaq/getting-information-about-objects-types-and-members-with-expression-trees) is another good article that you can use.

Comment: nice post Decy , that answer is really nice ,expression tree is what im looking for, thanks...